# change vba lookup function into event with vba array and dictionary

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

the data record in the "MASTERVALIDATION" sheet there are approximately one hundred thousand records please the solution so that it can run fast and if I use the vba function it makes the processor calculations so slow.

Thanks
SHEETS-MASTERVALIDATION : Source data
[SHEETS-MASTERVALIDATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URBzx.jpg)

in this below sheet I input through the code column then it appears in the item column that is looking for or lookup from the "MASTERVALIDATION" sheet
SHEETS-SEARCH
[SHEETS-SEARCH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqQ2t.jpg)

```
'Previously I used the excel formula array below
={IF(A2="","",INDEX(MASTERVALIDATION[[ITEM]:[CODE]],MATCH(TRUE,EXACT(A2,MASTERVALIDATION[CODE]),0),1))}
```

```
Function toItem(c As Range) As String
Dim f As Range

Set f = Sheets("MASTERVALIDATION").ListObjects("MASTERVALIDATION").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.Find(What:=c.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, lookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        toItem = f.Offset(, -1).Value
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want/need... 1. Do you mean that calling `toItem` function does it take to much time to return, **for one item**? 2. If not, how to you use the returned string? Do you use the function to process a big range and return the function result in cells, by iteration? If not, please better describe all process. Eventually, the other piece of code calling the function. 3. Why do you need a dictionary? Are there not unique strings/codes and need cumulating/concatenating their values? If not,  a dictionary is not of any help to increase the code speed.

Comment: We can imagine an appropriate array use only if we can see your code calling the function, or you better explain the context: How many such values must be returned at a code run? Are those "one hundred thousand records" In the table to be populate with the necessary data, or the data range where they must be taken from?

Comment: @FaneDuru ,
thanks for your reply. Is it possible to use the change event with an array?. one hundred thousand rows are data sources that are in the "MASTERVALIDATION" sheet and the "SEARCH" sheet or search for from the "MASTERVALIDATION" sheet, not up to one hundred thousand, only around ten thousand or two thousand.
So the "SEARCH" sheet where the sheet inputs the code then retrieves the items in the "MASTERVALIDATION" sheet

Comment: 1. Yes, an array can be used in an event. Why are you talking now about this issue? What event and how do you intend using it? Usually, an event (`Change`, for instance) is triggered on a change is made in the respective sheet and it usually updates something based on the respective change. Why needing an array? 2. You did not answer my questions related to the code calling the shown function and in which context the code you try takes long time.

Comment: @FaneDuru , `2. You did not answer my questions related to the code calling the shown function and in which context the code you try takes long time.` `Function toItem(c As Range) As String` This vba function code makes it take a long time if I input up to thousands of rows of records and also makes excel not responding

Comment: @FaneDuru , `1. Yes, an array can be used in an event. Why are you talking now about this issue? What event and how do you intend using it? Usually, an event (Change, for instance) is triggered on a change is made in the respective sheet and it usually updates something based on the respective change. Why needing an array?` if using an array is faster and I want to use the change event so the process is like using the vba function. Any faster recommendations?

Comment: I cannot get you, sorry. What do you mean by **if I input up to thousands of rows of records**? Where to **input** those rows?

Comment: It looks we are speaking different languages and I am not referring to English... An array cannot be faster. It can only be loaded in memory (fast) and drop the result at once (also fast). I am afraid I cannot help you.

Comment: @FaneDuru , `I cannot get you, sorry. What do you mean by if I input up to thousands of rows of records? Where to input those rows?` in this "SEARCH" sheet I input through the code column then it appears in the item column that is looking for or lookup from the "MASTERVALIDATION" sheet .
I've updated the description in the post sorry if I can't explain or make or make you don't understand

Comment: @FaneDuru,    `It looks we are speaking different languages and I am not referring to English... An array cannot be faster. It can only be loaded in memory (fast) and drop the result at once (also fast). I am afraid I cannot help you.` 
so I follow the best recommendations from you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess you mean something like this (untested):

```vb
Function toItem(c As Range) As String
    Static dict As Object
    Dim arr, arr2, r As Long, v
    
    If dict Is Nothing Then  'need to create the lookup dictionary?
        Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        dict.comparemode = 1 'vbTextCompare
        With Sheets("MASTERVALIDATION").ListObjects("MASTERVALIDATION").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange
            arr = .Value
            arr2 = .Offset(, -1).Value 'one column to the left
            'arr2 = .Offset(, 1).Value 'one column to the right
        End With
        For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1) 'fill the dictionary
            dict(CStr(arr(r, 1))) = arr2(r, 1)
        Next r
    End If
    v = CStr(c.Value)
    'return a value if c has any content and there's a match in the dictionary
    If Lev(v) > 0 And dict.exists(v) Then toItem = dict(v)
End Function
```

You would then have to manage the static dictionary in the event the source data gets changed though...

Comment: thanks for your reply. Sorry I'm late to reply to you. One more thing if the "MASTERVALIDATION" sheet for the item column changes from column "A" to column "C" then I have to change it in your code in which part of the code

Comment: can the code from you if the "code" column in the "SEARCH" sheet is empty then the "item" column is empty

Comment: You’d change to `.Offset(,1)`

Comment: A couple of edits above